# MVC partial view controller not running on load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Im trying to load a MVC partial view in to a modal popup. The popup contains a drop down list which I am trying to populate on the ActionResult that loads when the view is loaded. The problem is the controller code isn't getting ran.

My code is as follows -

View:

```
<div id="modal_form_horizontal_addnote" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h5 class="modal-title">Add Note</h5>
        </div>

        @Html.Partial("AddNote", new IHD.Core.Models.CreateTicketNoteModel { TicketHeaderId = Model.Id })
    </div>
</div>
```

The partial view:

```
@model IHD.Core.Models.CreateTicketNoteModel


@using (Html.BeginForm("AddNote", "Ticket", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TicketHeaderId)
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="highlighted-justified-tab1">

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WorkType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.WorkType, new SelectList(Model.WorkTypeOptions, "Key", "Value", Model.WorkType), new { @name = "select", @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WorkType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

The controller:

```
public ActionResult AddNotePhase(int id = 0, int taskId = 0)
    {
        CreateTicketPhaseNoteModel note = new CreateTicketPhaseNoteModel();
        note.TicketHeaderId = id;

        // Populate the work type dropdown list
        note.WorkTypeOptions.Add("", "-- Select a Work Type --");
        note.WorkTypes = _workTypeService.GetAll().ToList();
        foreach (var c in note.WorkTypes)
        {
            note.WorkTypeOptions.Add(c.Id.ToString(), c.Description);
        }

        //note.PhaseTask = taskId;

        return PartialView(note);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You controller code isn't being hit because you are passing a model to the partial view and not calling the action. You need to use `@{Html.RenderAction();}` instead to call your action with the appropriate values.

Comment: I would just add that @dynmatt could use the shorter markup : @Html.Action("AddNotePhase", "Ticket")

Comment: @Phteven yes, or that. I guess it's down to personal preference :)

Comment: @John thanks, it hits the controller now but the id parameter that im apssing to the controller is now 0.

Comment: Are you passing the Id through? `@{Html.RenderAction("Action", "Controller", new { id = model.Id });}` for example.

Comment: Yes - @Html.Action("AddNote", new IHD.Core.Models.CreateTicketNoteModel { TicketHeaderId = Model.Id })

Comment: @dynmatt You don't need `IHD.Core.Models.CreateTicketNoteModel`, just `new {id = Model.Id}`